# Interfaces vs abstract classes for immutable DTOs

Tags: java, interfaces, immutability, abstract-class, domain-objects

At my org we extensively use [`@Value.Immutable` annotation](https://www.baeldung.com/immutables) to generate `Immutable` classes (usually with `builder`s) for our internal data transfer objects (DTOs). In our codebase I've seen both `interface`s and `abstract class`es being used for such DTO definitions.

For example for a `DeviceData` DTO we could have an interface as follows

```
@Value.Immutable
@JsonDeserialize(as = ImmutableDeviceData.class)
public interface DeviceData {

    @Value.Parameter
    DeviceIdentifier deviceIdentifier();

    @Value.Parameter
    DeviceType deviceType(); // enum
}
```

or equivalently we could have abstract class with identical body as above interface

`public` **`abstract class`** `DeviceData {`

---

Either ways, we instantiate the DTO as follows

```
final var myDeviceData = ImmutableDeviceData.builder()
                             .deviceIdentifier(ImmutableDeviceIdentifier.of("xxxx-xxxx")
                             .deviceType(DeviceType.Tablet)
                             .build();
```

---

At times we also add certain [precondition checks using `@Value.Check` annotations](https://immutables.github.io/immutable.html#check-method) such as following, which again work identically with both `interface` and `abstract class`es

```
@Value.Immutable(builder = false)
public abstract class DeviceIdentifier {
    @Value.Parameter
    public String value();

    @Value.Check
    default void validate() {
        Validate.notBlank(value(), "DeviceIdentifier cannot be blank");
    }
}
```

Additionally there are situations where we have to declare static fields such as regex `Pattern` in case of `EmailAddress` DTO; here again Java17 makes it possible in both abstract class and interfaces alike.

---

Considering this specific use case of **Immutable data-transfer objects**, are there any pros or cons of preferring `abstract class` over `interface` or vice-versa?

Comment: The pros and cons for using an abstract class vs an interface *in this particular scenario* are the same pros and cons you would have *in any other scenario.*

Comment: I believe that @RobertHarvey is correct in his assessment.  Are you looking for the advantages and disadvantages in general or do you think there's something in particular in this specific case that we aren't seeing.

Comment: I'm starting out writing a new project from scratch and want to understand which of these two would be the better choice given the immutable DTOs use-case. Particularly I'm interested in understanding if there are any pitfalls associated with either of the approaches.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I think this particular scenario, there are *fewer* pros and cons. In this case `interface` vs `class` is barely distinguishable.

Comment: Since you mention you're using Java 17, is there any particular reason that you can't use records instead of this `Immutables` library? Records support everything in the question apart from the builder pattern for creation; they're simpler, less astonishing and built-in, but this is the first I've heard of the library so don't know if the builder pattern is a dealbreaker for you or if the library's got some other extra features that records don't.

Comment: @justme primary reason we don't want to *completely* move over to `record`s is that there's limited support for implementing builder-pattern with them [[ref-1](https://howtodoinjava.com/java/basics/builder-pattern-for-java-records/), [ref-2](https://github.com/immutables/immutables/issues/1484)]. We have presently decided to use `record`s for the 'tiny' DTOs such as `Coordinate`, but for complex ones having many `Optional`s we are continuing to use `abstract class`

Comment: Why would you want to tie DTOs from one to another? Each DTO should stand on it's own 2 feet allowing for easy updates to the DTO in future.

Answer (score 1):

There's not much in it, either way. The consistency you gain from picking one and sticking with it is likely to be more benefit than any potential drawbacks of either option.

---

That said, there are some minor differences:

- If any of these are inner classes, you need to remember to make them static (as per the [documentation](http://immutables.github.io/immutable.html#value)). If it was an inner interface, it would be static implicitly.
- Abstract methods on classes may have different access modifiers, whereas interface methods are implicitly public. Would you find a package access getter useful (bearing in mind the builder method will [still be public](http://immutables.github.io/immutable.html#non-public-attributes)), or would you prefer everything to be consistently and implicitly public?
- The library can be [configured](http://immutables.github.io/immutable.html#default-attributes) to use default interface methods to provide default values for parameters. If using abstract classes, you'd need to use an annotation on the method instead (this is also the default behaviour for interfaces).